# Is there always a full specification of a sigma algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Sigma$ be a $\sigma$-algebra of "events" on a set $\Omega$ of "histories". Given that the histories themselves need not be included in $\Sigma$, my question is: for any history, is there always an event in $\Sigma$ that *fully specifies* all the other events that happen?

Let me make this formal. Take a history $h \in \Omega$ and the set $S = \{e \in \Sigma | h \in e \}$ of events that "happen" given $h$. Can I always find an event $f \in \Sigma$ such that, for all  $e \in \Sigma$,

\begin{equation}
f \subseteq e \Leftrightarrow e \in S?
\end{equation}

Comment: If such an $f$ exists, it must be equal to $\bigcap S$, so we're looking for a $\sigma$-algebra that does not include a certain intersection of its members. This seems tricky, since $\sigma$-algebras are closed under countable intersections. Maybe you could take the [Borel $\sigma$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set) on a space that lacks some [countability property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_countability).

Comment: Yeah, I think $\Omega=$ [$[0,\omega_1]$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-countable_space#Examples_and_counterexamples) should work (but not quite the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on it). Let $\Sigma$ consist of the sets bounded above by a countable ordinal, plus the complements of these sets.